# Ii know Django and flutter. Would it be possible to use these two to make a website? if yes, could we use the same code for the mobile app?

Tags: django, flutter, web, dart, mobile

I wanted to build a website for someone. I know Django and flutter. would it be possible to use these two to make a website? If yes can we use the same code for the mobile app?
If you know the answer would you be kind enough to enter the steps or the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> would it be possible to use these two to make a website?

You can definitely build a website with Flutter. This is in beta however so be aware of that. Simply run these commands then you can compile to chrome instead of iOS / Android.

```
    flutter channel beta
    flutter upgrade
    flutter config --enable-web
```

Source: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web